# Selenium find what the text is in input field

Tags: python, selenium

I have a input field that I need to confirm has text in it. I don't care what is in it; just that there is text in it, that that text is a number and what that number is.

I have tried `get_attribute()` and that is giving me nothing.

This is an example of the html:

```
<td>
    <input id="quota" type="text" value="100.0" name="quota" size="3"></input>MB (0 for unlimited)
</td>
```

I am writing the tests in python.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `get_attribute("value")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no text inside that input.

If you are trying to get the `100.0`, then you need to select the input element, and then do `get_attribute("value")`.

If you want the `MB (0 for unlimited)`, then you need to select the text inside the `td` element.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just needed "value". If I could vote you'd get a +1!